# error on kernel compilation for Sony Z3 tablet compact - board-8974-gpiomux.c - 'gpio_spi_config'

Tags: android, c, makefile, linux-kernel, sony

I' trying to build a kernel for a Sony Xperia Z3 Tablet compact following this guide:

http://developer.sonymobile.com/knowledge-base/open-source/open-devices/how-to-build-and-flash-a-linux-kernel/how-to-build-and-flash-a-linux-kernel-for-aosp-supported-devices/

The error I receive is the following upon 
`make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=$CROSS_COMPILE -j4`

```
...
  CC      kernel/exec_domain.o
  CC      arch/arm/mach-msm/board-8974-gpiomux.o
  AS      arch/arm/mm/tlb-v7.o
  AS      arch/arm/mm/proc-v7.o
  CC      mm/mempool.o
arch/arm/mach-msm/board-8974-gpiomux.c:692:24: error: 'gpio_spi_config' undeclared here (not in a function)
    [GPIOMUX_ACTIVE] = &gpio_spi_config,
                        ^
  LD      arch/arm/mm/built-in.o
scripts/Makefile.build:308: die Regel für Ziel „arch/arm/mach-msm/board-8974-gpiomux.o“ scheiterte
make[1]: *** [arch/arm/mach-msm/board-8974-gpiomux.o] Fehler 1
Makefile:815: die Regel für Ziel „arch/arm/mach-msm“ scheiterte
make: *** [arch/arm/mach-msm] Fehler 2
make: *** Auf noch nicht beendete Prozesse wird gewartet …
  CC      mm/oom_kill.o
  CC      kernel/panic.o
  CC      kernel/printk.o
  CC      kernel/cpu.o
  CC      mm/fadvise.o
...
```

as proposed in the HowTo I did following steps:

1. installed 4.8 cross compile toolchain and exported CROSS_COMPILE var
2. cloned kernel repository
3. took aosp_shinano_scorpion_defconfig from aosp repository
4. updated the config
5. ran the above mentioned build command

As I could see in the `board-8974-gpiomux.c` the declaration of the `gpio_spi_config`struct is inside an `ifdef`, but the call where the error occured is outside the scope of the `ifdef` condition.

So it seems logical to me, that the compiler complains about that. But I also doubt an error in the source, because I'm quite certain that I'm not the first one following that guide.

Any ideas?

Thanks and regards,
Timo

Comment: what is the `#ifdef` checking?   Is the condition set `true` in the configuration file?

Comment: It is checking for `#if defined(CONFIG_KS8851) || defined(CONFIG_KS8851_MODULE)`. Those are not defined in the config file.

Comment: Since those are hardware oriented configuration items, perhaps they should be defined in the configuration file.

Comment: I think you are right on mentioning that it is hardware-related. But the config file I used was preconfigured for my exact device. And why should the same struct be used in the same file outside the `#ifdef` condition? During build I ran into several other failures in other files. Some of them where just warnings defined as errors such as `'unused-variable'` some where more serious errors such as `missmatching Pointer assignment`. I think their Kernel is buggy. I'm investigatig further. Thanks for your help so far

Answer (score -1):

He is right.
In file `"board-8974-gpiomux.c"` we see `"#if defined(CONFIG_KS8851) || defined(CONFIG_KS8851_MODULE)"`. It means if at least one of these has been enabled then gcc will see the definitions in this section.
enabling `"CONFIG_KS8851=y"` in the config file passed this for me.